# How to run JSON using java

Tags: java, json

few days ago i've started studing on json. i've got a code of json but i m unabe to run this code.
please guide me what should i do !!
where and how should i run this code?

```
{
"title":"About Canada",
"rows":[
    {
    "title":"Beavers",
    "description":"Beavers are second only to humans in their ability to manipulate and change their environment. They can measure up to 1.3 metres long. A group of beavers is called a colony",
    "imageHref":"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6b/American_Beaver.jpg/220px-American_Beaver.jpg"
    },
    {
    "title":"Flag",
    "description":null,
    "imageHref":"http://images.findicons.com/files/icons/662/world_flag/128/flag_of_canada.png"
    },
    {
    "title":"Transportation",
    "description":"It is a well known fact that polar bears are the main mode of transportation in Canada. They consume far less gas and have the added benefit of being difficult to steal.",
    "imageHref":"http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_VZVOmYVm68Q/SMkzZzkGXKI/AAAAAAAAADQ/U89miaCkcyo/s400/the_golden_compass_still.jpg"
    },
    {
    "title":"Hockey Night in Canada",
    "description":"These Saturday night CBC broadcasts originally aired on radio in 1931. In 1952 they debuted on television and continue to unite (and divide) the nation each week.",
    "imageHref":"http://fyimusic.ca/wp-content/uploads/2008/06/hockey-night-in-canada.thumbnail.jpg"
    },
    {
    "title":"Eh",
    "description":"A chiefly Canadian interrogative utterance, usually expressing surprise or doubt or seeking confirmation.",
    "imageHref":null
    },
    {
    "title":"Housing",
    "description":"Warmer than you might think.",
    "imageHref":"http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconshock/alaska/256/Igloo-icon.png"
    },
    {
    "title":"Public Shame",
    "description":" Sadly it's true.",
    "imageHref":"http://static.guim.co.uk/sys-images/Music/Pix/site_furniture/2007/04/19/avril_lavigne.jpg"
    },
    {
    "title":null,
    "description":null,
    "imageHref":null
    },
    {
    "title":"Space Program",
    "description":"Canada hopes to soon launch a man to the moon.",
    "imageHref":"http://files.turbosquid.com/Preview/Content_2009_07_14__10_25_15/trebucheta.jpgdf3f3bf4-935d-40ff-84b2-6ce718a327a9Larger.jpg"
    },
    {
    "title":"Meese",
    "description":"A moose is a common sight in Canada. Tall and majestic, they represent many of the values which Canadians imagine that they possess. They grow up to 2.7 metres long and can weigh over 700 kg. They swim at 10 km/h. Moose antlers weigh roughly 20 kg. The plural of moose is actually 'meese', despite what most dictionaries, encyclopedias, and experts will tell you.",
    "imageHref":"http://caroldeckerwildlifeartstudio.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/IMG_2418%20majestic%20moose%201%20copy%20(Small)-96x96.jpg"
    },
    {
    "title":"Geography",
    "description":"It's really big.",
    "imageHref":null
    },
    {
    "title":"Kittens...",
    "description":"Éare illegal. Cats are fine.",
    "imageHref":"http://www.donegalhimalayans.com/images/That%20fish%20was%20this%20big.jpg"
    },
    {
    "title":"Mounties",
    "description":"They are the law. They are also Canada's foreign espionage service. Subtle.",
    "imageHref":"http://3.bp.blogspot.com/__mokxbTmuJM/RnWuJ6cE9cI/AAAAAAAAATw/6z3m3w9JDiU/s400/019843_31.jpg"
    },
    {
    "title":"Language",
    "description":"Nous parlons tous les langues importants.",
    "imageHref":null
    }
]
}
```

Comment: You can't "run" json data, it is just ... data.

Comment: Google provides [a good json encoding/decoding library](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/). Look at their tutorials.

Comment: Start with Hello World in Java.

Comment: You could use MOXy to covert your JSON document to Java objects:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/08/json-binding-with-eclipselink-moxy.html.  Based on the contents of your sample document you'll be interested to know the core MOXy committers are Canadian.  Happy Canada Day!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this http://www.json.org/java/.

JSon is data similiar to XML . However without end tags . So you would point to that file and have one of the json parsers look at it and call functions to get the data inside each attribute . If you are having problems using one of the json libraries post up the code your trying to use and we will help you out .

http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/

That's a really simple json library ( pun intended ) I think the easiest to get started with , let us know if you have any trouble with it .

Answer (score 1):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

**DOMAIN MODEL**

You will want some sort of data structure to represent your JSON data so that you can work with it in your Java application.  Below is an example of using a typed domain model.  Other JSON libraries offer a more generic DOM like structure.

***Search***

```
package forum11283724;

import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Search {

    String title;
    List<Book> rows;

}
```

***Book***

```
package forum11283724;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Book {
    String title;
    String description;
    String imageHref;
}
```

**DEMO CODE**

Below is code sample that read the JSON document into Java objects, and then writes them back to JSON.  When the data is in object form you could act on it:  add, remove, modify, etc.

***Demo***

```
package forum11283724;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextProperties;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Map<String,Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>(2);
        properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.MEDIA_TYPE, "application/json");
        properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.JSON_INCLUDE_ROOT, false);
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] {Search.class}, properties);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        StreamSource json = new StreamSource(new FileReader("src/forum11283724/input.json"));
        Search search = (Search) unmarshaller.unmarshal(json, Search.class).getValue();

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(search, System.out);
    }

}
```

**INPUT/OUTPUT**

Below is your JSON document which is the input/output for this example

```
{
   "title" : "About Canada",
   "rows" : [ {
      "title" : "Beavers",
      "description" : "Beavers are second only to humans in their ability to manipulate and change their environment. They can measure up to 1.3 metres long. A group of beavers is called a colony",
      "imageHref" : "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6b/American_Beaver.jpg/220px-American_Beaver.jpg"
   }, {
      "title" : "Flag",
      "imageHref" : "http://images.findicons.com/files/icons/662/world_flag/128/flag_of_canada.png"
   }, {
      "title" : "Transportation",
      "description" : "It is a well known fact that polar bears are the main mode of transportation in Canada. They consume far less gas and have the added benefit of being difficult to steal.",
      "imageHref" : "http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_VZVOmYVm68Q/SMkzZzkGXKI/AAAAAAAAADQ/U89miaCkcyo/s400/the_golden_compass_still.jpg"
   }, {
      "title" : "Hockey Night in Canada",
      "description" : "These Saturday night CBC broadcasts originally aired on radio in 1931. In 1952 they debuted on television and continue to unite (and divide) the nation each week.",
      "imageHref" : "http://fyimusic.ca/wp-content/uploads/2008/06/hockey-night-in-canada.thumbnail.jpg"
   }, {
      "title" : "Eh",
      "description" : "A chiefly Canadian interrogative utterance, usually expressing surprise or doubt or seeking confirmation."
   }, {
      "title" : "Housing",
      "description" : "Warmer than you might think.",
      "imageHref" : "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconshock/alaska/256/Igloo-icon.png"
   }, {
      "title" : "Public Shame",
      "description" : " Sadly it's true.",
      "imageHref" : "http://static.guim.co.uk/sys-images/Music/Pix/site_furniture/2007/04/19/avril_lavigne.jpg"
   }, {
   }, {
      "title" : "Space Program",
      "description" : "Canada hopes to soon launch a man to the moon.",
      "imageHref" : "http://files.turbosquid.com/Preview/Content_2009_07_14__10_25_15/trebucheta.jpgdf3f3bf4-935d-40ff-84b2-6ce718a327a9Larger.jpg"
   }, {
      "title" : "Meese",
      "description" : "A moose is a common sight in Canada. Tall and majestic, they represent many of the values which Canadians imagine that they possess. They grow up to 2.7 metres long and can weigh over 700 kg. They swim at 10 km/h. Moose antlers weigh roughly 20 kg. The plural of moose is actually 'meese', despite what most dictionaries, encyclopedias, and experts will tell you.",
      "imageHref" : "http://caroldeckerwildlifeartstudio.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/IMG_2418%20majestic%20moose%201%20copy%20(Small)-96x96.jpg"
   }, {
      "title" : "Geography",
      "description" : "It's really big."
   }, {
      "title" : "Kittens...",
      "description" : "√âare illegal. Cats are fine.",
      "imageHref" : "http://www.donegalhimalayans.com/images/That%20fish%20was%20this%20big.jpg"
   }, {
      "title" : "Mounties",
      "description" : "They are the law. They are also Canada's foreign espionage service. Subtle.",
      "imageHref" : "http://3.bp.blogspot.com/__mokxbTmuJM/RnWuJ6cE9cI/AAAAAAAAATw/6z3m3w9JDiU/s400/019843_31.jpg"
   }, {
      "title" : "Language",
      "description" : "Nous parlons tous les langues importants."
   } ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once You have the data in json format , you can use it as a response for some of your request and to show it to the client (browser) you need to loop through it using **javascript** for loop .

Comment: What does this have to do with Java?

Comment: Java can be used to create json object . Take a look at this http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html

Comment: Yes, I know-my point was that the OP is asking about Java/JSON, which your answer ignores.